# Missing application from sdcard

Tags: applications, sd-card, backup

I did factory reset. So, I lost application from sdcard but that application files still exist in sdcard.

How do I recovery my application from sdcard. I do not have back up app data file.

My phone is version 4.0.4 and non-rooted device.

Comment: If you have no backup, there's nothing you can recover from. That's like asking how to open the door of a non-existing car.

Answer (score 0):

On SD Card stored only application data, but some parts of applications are always stored on phone, so recovery is impossible - only reinstall.